# I am trying to translate the seal on a vase. please help (Characters identified: 蔣松林印)

Tags: character-identification, seal

Trying to find information regarding Seal mark on
Vase.

[image]

Comment: BTW the picture is upside down.

Comment: there’s another porcelain vase made by the same author, one might compare the seal :) https://www.ruten.com.tw/item/show?21942440752291

Comment: @stan, “down-size-up” now 

Answer (score 2):

The seal says

> 蔣松林印
>
> Seal of 蔣松林

So the craftsperson's name is 蔣松林 (Mandarin: Jiǎng Sōnglín).